# Implicit casting like shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, templates, casting

When using `std::shared_ptr<>` it's possible to cast from `shared_ptr<T>` to `shared_ptr<U>` if U is a base of T.

I'm trying to achieve the same thing, I have a template class that wraps a pointer and I'd like the same derived-to-base conversion to work, how is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in **one** of two ways:

- converting constructor
- converting operator

Examples:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    // converting constructor
    template <typename U>
    explicit MyClass(MyClass<U> const& other);

    // converting operator
    template <typename U>
    explicit operator MyClass<U>() const; // explicit here is C++11 only
};
```

If you do both though, you will unfortunately have ambiguous conversions. Personally I find the converting constructor easier (and more idiomatic) and reserve the use of the converting operators to situations when I cannot modify the converted-to class (not my code).

Comment: Thanks! I'm still unsure how shared_ptr<> only allows casts where T is a subclass of U but in my particular case, I'm wrapping shared_ptr<> so the compiler will complain anyhow.

Comment: @Kazade: You have two solutions. `std::shared_ptr<T>` wraps a `T*`, so when assigning to `T*` from `U*` the compiler will naturally check for a conversion and complain if it is not possible; the only disadvantage is that error occurs possibly deep in the templates. The other solution is to explicitly guard the constructor with a SFINAE check; it is more complicated to write, and has the issue that it removes the constructor from the set of considered overloads which might give an even weirder error message.